# If $\sigma_n^2<\infty$ and $E[X_n]\ne0$ then $\frac{\sigma_n^2}{E[X_n]^2}\to0$ implies $\frac{X_n}{E[X_n]}\overset{P}\longrightarrow1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:** Suppose that the random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ have finite variances and nonzero means. Show the following statement:
$$\text{if }\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma_n^2}{E[X_n]^2}=0\text{ then }\frac{X_n}{E[X_n]}\overset{P}\longrightarrow1.$$

**Attempt:** Fix $\varepsilon>0$. An application of Chebyshev's inequality yields
$$P\left(\left\vert \frac{X_n}{E[X_n]}-1\right\vert\geq\varepsilon\right)=P\left(\left\vert X_n-E[X_n]\right\vert\geq\varepsilon \vert E[X_n]\vert\right)\leq\frac{\sigma_n^2}{\varepsilon^2 E[X_n]^2}\overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0,$$
where in the last step we used the assumption that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma_n^2}{E[X_n]^2}=0.$ Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary it follows that $\frac{X_n}{E[X_n]}\overset{P}\longrightarrow1$ as $n\to\infty.$

---

Do you agree with my attempt at a proof of the above exercise?
Any feedback is much welcomed and appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, this is probably right. I like this interpretation : as $n$ increases, the variance starts mattering less and less with respect to the mean. Therefore, for large $n$, the random variable does not sway too far from its expectation in probability.